# HeidiSQL: Connect to SQL Server on non-standard Port

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, heidisql

I am trying to connect to a database instance on a box running SQL Server Express Edition. The instance is running on port 54759, rather than the default 1433 typically used by Microsoft SQL Server.

I can successfully connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, by specifying the server name as `my-server-name,54759`. However, when I try the same hostname in HeidiSQL I get the following error:

`SQL Error(0): Operation is not allowed when the object is closed
unknown`

I cannot find any option in HeidiSQL to change the default port for a Microsoft SQL Server instance, nor any reference to a particular syntax to use for specifying the port number.

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Have you tried a colon `:` with the port number after it?

Comment: Isn't there an input box labelled "Port:" in the session manager underneath Username and Password? There is on my Portable version of HeidiSQL.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I tried colon and various other characters I could think were plausable. In all cases it seemed to think these were part of the server name, and timed out "SQL server does not exist..." error

Comment: @JNevill There is. For MySQL and PostgreSQL it can be set, but oddly for Microsoft SQL connections it is greyed out, set to 1433, and not adjustable.

Comment: Not sure if you can, but have you tried an `ODBC` connection?

Comment: @Mike That makes sense. It looks like the TCP type connection allows it, but not sure if that works for SQL Server Express.

Comment: Turns out the comma syntax does work after all having restarted HeidiSQL, I can now connect fine and can't replicate the error. Should have switched it off and on again! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the comma syntax does work in HeidiSQL after all: `[server-name],[port number]` in the Hostname/IP box.

The cause of the error must have been unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

In HeidiSQL, the port for MS SQL Server connections can only be changed if you selected *Microsoft SQL Server (**TCP/IP**)*. In that case you use the "Port" setting, below the "Password" field.

For the other network types - IPX, Banyans and RPC - you cannot define a port as that makes no sense in these protocols.